# practical use of a Boltzmann machine

Tags: reference-request, neural-networks, boltzmann-machine

I am reading "Neural Networks and Learning Machines" and in Chapter 11 the book covers Boltzman machines and it is stated "the network [Boltzmann machine] can perform pattern completion", but does not show how this would be done in practice, or how a Boltzmann machine could be used at all.

As I am more the "hands-on" person, and the book is more on the theoretical side of science. I am currently looking for an practical example/paper/article on an Boltzmann machine, maybe even a simple (therefore small) educational implementation.

I'd appreciate any link/paper/article covering the (**non-restricted**) Boltzmann machine in an understandable ("hands-on") way.